# How to exclude branches to build in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

In Source Code Management tab, I could specify branch specifier to track `/feature/AEAZ-*` branchs in a repository.
It will track all branches whose name include `/feature/AEAZ-`. Now I want to exclude some branches like `/feature/AEAZ-1234` which includes `/feature/AEAZ-` .
How to specify branch specifier?
Jenkins Git plugin says it can use **regular expression**. I'm not familar with it. Could you tell me how to implement this requirement?

Could I use `:/feature/AEAZ-(?!(1234)).*` to exclude `/feature/AEAZ-1234`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
/\/feature\/AEAZ\-(?!1234).*/
```

notes :

- Characters like / or - have to be escaped with a \ to be considered as simple chars without their special behaviour in regexp patterns.
- (?!something) to exclude `something` trailing
- The outer / I've put around the regexp may not be needed in jenkins UI

Comment: It seems that there's no need to escape `/` and `-` in jenkins. `:origin/feature/AEAZ-(?!(1234$)).*` can work.